# stop postback on treeview node click

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, postback

I followed this tutorial to allow a user to select a folder from their machine:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21895/Directory-Browsing-in-ASP-Net

The problem is that every time I click on a node, it calls postback, which refreshes the page. So how do I stop postback being called every time?

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" Height="326px" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer"
                                            NodeIndent="15" Width="292px">
                                            <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                                            <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
                                            <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px"
                                                VerticalPadding="0px" />
                                            <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="2px"
                                                NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                                            <LeafNodeStyle  ImageUrl="../images/folder.gif" />
                                        </asp:TreeView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                TreeNode onjParent = new TreeNode("C:\\", "C:\\");
                onjParent.PopulateOnDemand = true;
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(onjParent);

                TreeView1.CollapseAll();
            }

            error.Visible = false;
            TreeView1.TreeNodeExpanded += new TreeNodeEventHandler(TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded);
            TreeView1.SelectedNodeChanged += new EventHandler(TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged);
        }

    void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _browseTextBox.Text = TreeView1.SelectedValue;
        }

        void TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Node.Value.EndsWith("\\"))
            {
                AddNodes(e.Node.Value, e.Node);
            }


        }
        private TreeNode AddNodes(string path, TreeNode parentNode)
        {
            FileList objList = new FileList(path, "*.*");
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(path, path);
            for (int index = 0; index < objList.Directories.Length; index++)
            {
                string directory = objList.Directories[index];
                TreeNode objChildNode = new TreeNode(directory, path + "\\" + directory + "\\");
                objChildNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
                objChildNode.Target = "_blank";

                parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(objChildNode);
            }
            foreach (string file in objList.Files)
            {
                TreeNode objChildNode = new TreeNode(file, path + "\\" + file);
                parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(objChildNode);
            }
            return node;
        }


        protected void _browseButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            if (UpdateBrowseTextBoxWithSlash())
            {

                TreeNode onjParent = new TreeNode(_browseTextBox.Text, _browseTextBox.Text);
                onjParent.PopulateOnDemand = true;
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(onjParent);

                TreeView1.CollapseAll();
            }
            else
            {
                error.Visible = true;
                error.Text = "Please Enter valid path";
            }
        }

        private bool UpdateBrowseTextBoxWithSlash()
        {
            if (_browseTextBox.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                if (
                        -1 == _browseTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(".") &&
                        !_browseTextBox.Text.Substring(_browseTextBox.Text.Length - 1, 1).Equals("/") &&
                        !_browseTextBox.Text.Substring(_browseTextBox.Text.Length - 1, 1).Equals("\\")
                    )
                {
                    if (_browseTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 1).Equals("\\") || -1 != _browseTextBox.Text.IndexOf(":\\"))
                        _browseTextBox.Text += "\\";
                    else
                        _browseTextBox.Text += "/";
                    return System.IO.Directory.Exists(_browseTextBox.Text);
                }
                else if (_browseTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(".") > 0)
                {
                    return System.IO.File.Exists(_browseTextBox.Text);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Might be you can use updatepanel

Comment: @KushalVora could you show some code on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Imperfect Solution To TreeView](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.presentation-controls/-imperfect-solution-to-treeview/467445)?  The author provides an interesting idea to omit postback when selecting a node by manually setting the NavigateUrl and SelectAction of each TreeNode.  From first glance, it appears logical.  The only thing missing is that it is not recursive so it can only handle one node level at a time.